# Customer data isn't being passed or stored in the session?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

For some reason my code is not adding customer to the session. I am new to ASP.NET does anyone have any input as to why this is happening and maybe able to give some code example. Thanks!

Below it the code.

```
Imports System.Data

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private SelectedCustomer As Customer

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
            Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            ddlCustomers.DataBind()
        End If
        SelectedCustomer = Me.GetSelectedCustomer
        Me.DisplayCustomer()
    End Sub

    Private Function GetSelectedCustomer() As Customer
        Dim dvTable As dataview = CType(AccessDataSource1.Select( _
            DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), dataview)
        dvTable.RowFilter = "CustomerID = " & ddlCustomers.SelectedValue
        Dim drvRow As DataRowView = dvTable(0)

        Dim customer As New Customer
        customer.CustomerID = CInt(drvRow("CustomerID"))
        customer.Name = drvRow("Name").ToString
        customer.Address = drvRow("Address").ToString
        customer.City = drvRow("City").ToString
        customer.State = drvRow("State").ToString
        customer.ZipCode = drvRow("ZipCode").ToString
        customer.Phone = drvRow("Phone").ToString
        customer.Email = drvRow("Email").ToString
        Return customer
    End Function

    Private Sub DisplayCustomer()
        lblAddress.Text = SelectedCustomer.Address
        lblCityStateZip.Text = SelectedCustomer.City & ", " _
                             & SelectedCustomer.State & " " _
                             & SelectedCustomer.ZipCode
        lblPhone.Text = SelectedCustomer.Phone
        lblEmail.Text = SelectedCustomer.Email
    End Sub


    Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        If Page.IsValid Then
            Dim customerItem As New Customer
            customerItem.Name = SelectedCustomer.ToString
            Me.AddToCustomer(customerItem)
            Response.Redirect("CustomerList.aspx")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddToCustomer(ByVal customerItem As Customer)
        Dim customer As SortedList = Me.GetCustomer
        Dim customerID As String = SelectedCustomer.CustomerID
        If customer.ContainsKey(customerID) Then
            customerItem = CType(customer(customerID), Customer)
        Else
            customer.Add(customerID, customerItem)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function GetCustomer() As SortedList
        If Session("Customer") Is Nothing Then
            Session.Add("Customer", New SortedList)
        End If
        Return CType(Session("Customer"), SortedList)
    End Function

End Class
```

Second page of code below:

```
Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private Customer As SortedList
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Customer = Me.GetCustomer
        If Not IsPostBack Then Me.DisplayCustomer()

    End Sub
    Private Function GetCustomer() As SortedList
        If Session("Customer") Is Nothing Then
            Session.Add("Customer", New SortedList)
        End If
        Return CType(Session("Customer"), SortedList)
    End Function
    Private Sub DisplayCustomer()
        lstCustomer.Items.Clear()
        Dim customerItem As Customer
        For Each customerEntry As DictionaryEntry In Customer
            customerItem = CType(customerEntry.Value, Customer)
            lstCustomer.Items.Add(customerItem.Name)
        Next
    End Sub

    Protected Sub lstCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstCustomer.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Clearbtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Clearbtn.Click
        If Customer.Count > 0 Then
            Customer.Clear()
            lstCustomer.Items.Clear()
        Else
            clrErr.Text = "ERROR: NO CUSTOMERS STORED"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've actually answered this in another of your questions

You need to add a line to actually store the updated customer object back into Session for example

```
Private Sub AddToCustomer(ByVal customerItem As Customer)
    Dim customer As SortedList = Me.GetCustomer
    Dim customerID As String = SelectedCustomer.CustomerID
    If customer.ContainsKey(customerID) Then
        customerItem = CType(customer(customerID), Customer)
    Else
        customer.Add(customerID, customerItem)
    End If
    Session("Customer") = customer
End Sub
```

Although I'd recommend you put this in another function so that your design doesn't depend on Session if you want to change it later on.  So more like

```
Private Sub AddToCustomer(ByVal customerItem As Customer)
    Dim customer As SortedList = Me.GetCustomer
    Dim customerID As String = SelectedCustomer.CustomerID
    If customer.ContainsKey(customerID) Then
        customerItem = CType(customer(customerID), Customer)
    Else
        customer.Add(customerID, customerItem)
    End If
    StoreCustomer(customer)
End Sub

Private Sub StoreCustomer(ByVal customer As SortedList)
   Session("Customer") = customer
End Sub
```

At the moment all local changes to customer are lost just after the call toto AddToCustomer as you then do a redirect after.

```
Me.AddToCustomer(customerItem)
Response.Redirect("CustomerList.aspx")
```